# Selenium - Unable to find the text inside a label

Tags: java, selenium, label

I want to extract the value which is appearing on the screen("70") in order to compare it with a value.

Have already tried `getText()`, `getAttribute` with different value - title, value, innerHTML, innerText. Unfortunately none of them worked.

Any idea on how we can do this?

```
 <label id="current_heat_setpoint" class="e_field_data_text">70</label>
```

**Note :**

I'm able to locate the element have have already made sure that it is the right one - `getAttribute("id")` returned "**current_heat_setpoint**".

Comment: Could it be that there are multiple elements with the same `current_heat_setpoint` id on the page?

Comment: @alecxe There is only one element with that ID, verified using FirePath.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Then sounds more like a timing issue. This is fine, but you need to take it into account. The theory is - the heat setpoint value is set dynamically after the page load and when you read the value, it is not yet set. If you think it could be true, I can provide you with a possible approach to solve it.

Comment: @alecxe Yes, it is a timing issue. It wasn't loaded even at the point in time I thought it was.

Comment: Yeah, sounds pretty much like a timing issue. Compiled a possible way to approach the problem in the answer below. Take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, this looks really like a timing issue - the text of the label is dynamically set and you need to wait for it to appear before getting it. This can be achieved with `WebDriverWait` and a *custom Expected Condition*:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement label = wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.id("current_heat_setpoint")).getText().length() > 0;
    }
});
System.out.println(label.getText());
```